# Term for piece of art independent of its form

Tags: word-request

Usually the terms "artwork", "piece of art" mean only visual content (drawings, photos). Is there a word or phrase that implies an artistic work of broader set of forms? First of all, I mean the literature: poems, books, stories, movies scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

"Usually", yes, and I think that's the point: a book, a poem, or a piece of music can definitely be called an '*artwork*', '*work of art*', or '*art piece*'.

I feel the problem derives from the fact that these terms are simply not used as often when it comes to works that don't depend as much on their appearance.

On the other hand, this could also simply indicate a change in the use of these words ('artwork', &c.): dictionary definitions for 'artwork' still refer often to (physical) products of the visual arts, but in the more colloquial references (like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_of_art)) this distinction is not as rigid.

Compare also these definitions of '*artwork*' and '*work of art*' from Lexico and Dictionary.com respectively:

- 'Artwork':

  > Illustrations, photographs, or other non-textual material prepared for inclusion in a publication.
  >
  > - Paintings, drawings, or other artistic works.

  > The production of artistic or craft objects.
  > The object so produced.
- 'Work of art':

  > A painting, sculpture, poem, piece of music, or other product of the creative arts, especially one with strong imaginative or aesthetic appeal.

  > A piece of creative work in the arts, especially a painting or sculpture.
  > A product that gives aesthetic pleasure and that can be judged separately from any utilitarian considerations.

As you can tell, '*artwork*' according to Lexico has that more exclusive meaning, whereas Dictionary.com has the more tolerant interpretation. With '*work of art*' (which in theory is very similar to 'artwork') it seems aesthetics are emphasized, and the medium doesn't matter nearly as much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Ok, but is there a way to highlight that I mean any form of art? I want the term to be understood correctly in the broad meaning in the cases when I mention the term for the first time, e.g saying "I used the artworks of mentioned copyright holders."

Comment: What's wrong with just _works_?

Comment: Works can be ambiguous (it can also mean things that aren't art, like construction works) but certainly fits in "I used the works of mentioned copyright holders". You could use "creative works" or something if it was ambiguous.